# How to append data while printing the entire webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been developing a webpage and in that i need to append extra data to some division while printing that page. Is there any way of doing ,if so please help .

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Make a dedicated page for printing out.

Comment: You should post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use CSS @media print

STYLE SHEET

```
<style type="text/css">

#appendonprint { display: none; }
@media print
{
    #appendonprint { display: block; }
}
</style>
```

Web Page

```
<p>
Web Page Contents Go Here
</p>

<div id="appendonprint">
Appended Data Here (only visible when printing)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having the data on the page in the first place, but **hidden**. You can use **print only specific css** to display this data on the printed version of the page.

See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options.

1. Use CSS `@media print {}` and append the data by default to your page.
2. Use Javascript to detect `beforePrint`. I found a good tutorial here: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/